# If $f(x) = x^3 + 4x^2 + ax + 1$ is a monotonically decreasing function of $x$ in $(-2, -\frac{2}{3})$ then find $a$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If  $f(x) =  x^3  + 4x^2  +  ax  + 1$ is a monotonically decreasing function of  $x$ in the largest possible interval$ (-2, -\frac{2}{3})$ then find $a$.

My work:
$$f'(x)=3x^2+8x+a$$
For it to be monotonically decreasing$$ f'(x)\lt 0$$
$$f'(x)=3x^2+8x+a \lt 0$$
$$D\lt0$$
$$64-12a\lt0$$
$$a\gt \frac{16}{3}$$
I am stuck here, what should I do next?

Comment: $f'(x)\leq 0$ in $(-2,-\frac{2}{3})$ and $f'(x)\geq 0$ in $(-\infty ,-2]\cup[-\frac{2}{3},+\infty )$.

Comment: It may be possible because question said largest possible interval of decreasing

Comment: Please tell me what information should I add to question

Comment: Try to find the largest possible interval within (-2, -2/3) ie find (d,e) and a where d > -2;e < -2/3;d <e; f'(d)=f'(e)=0.  Try to set up a function g (a) = e -d and find its maximum.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are saying ?

Answer (score 0):

We write that $f $ is decreasing on the interval $(d,e) \subset (-2,-2/3) $.

This means $f'(d) = 0$; $f'(e)=0$ and $f'(a)<0$ and $-2 \le d < e \le -2/3$

So $3d^2 + 8d + a = 0$.  Solve for $d $ in terms of $a$.  There will be 2 possible expressions but hopefully only one will satisfy $a > 16/3$ and $-2 \le d \le -2/3$.  Let's call this expression $d (a)$

Do the same thing for $e$ to get $e (a) $.

We want the maximum such interval.  I.e. $e (a)-d (a) $ is maximal.  So solve for $e'(a) - d'(a)=0$.  That will be the largest interval in which any such $f $ is decreasing.